# CSS Image Position

Tags: css

I'm trying to get an div with image background to appear to the right of a text box. I have tried Float = none, left, right, I have tried position and even played with margins but nothing seems to get it to stay.

```
<div id="status" style="background-image:url(menubar/ajax-loader.gif); width:16px; height:16px; background-repeat:no-repeat; margin-left: 245px; margin-top: 2px;"></div>


<input name="strsearch" style="color:#333" type="text" id="strsearch" onKeyUp="Search(this.form)" value="Please enter your search criteria..." size="35" maxlength="75" onFocus="clearfield();" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's that work for ya?

```
<input name="strsearch" style="color:#333" type="text" id="strsearch" onKeyUp="Search(this.form)" value="Please enter your search criteria..." size="35" maxlength="75" onFocus="clearfield();" />

<div id="status" style="display:inline;background-image:url(menubar/ajax-loader.gif); width:16px; height:16px; background-repeat:no-repeat;padding-right:16px;"></div>​
```

float left and right try to throw your element as far to one side of the container as possible. If you want the element on the right side of a second element, put it after the second element in your HTML. Also, `div`s are block elements. Block elements want to be on their own line. Use an inline element (like a `span`), or set the `display` css property to `inline` on a block element you don't want on a new line.

EDIT: Here it is as a span for ya

```
<input name="strsearch" style="color:#333" type="text" id="strsearch" onKeyUp="Search(this.form)" value="Please enter your search criteria..." size="35" maxlength="75" onFocus="clearfield();" />

<span id="status" style="background-image:url(menubar/ajax-loader.gif); width:16px; height:16px; background-repeat:no-repeat;padding-right:16px;"></span>​
```

Comment: That did it thank you! Can you tell me what I was doing wrong? I tried putting it on the right and even tried align left but it just wouldn't do it.

Comment: Now your using display=inline... I need to change that to none. Will that mess things up? The image is an ajax loader image which is only shown when a search is performing.

Comment: nope. changing it to `display: none` is no big deal. just remember that it needs to be `display: inline` when you want to show it again. or use a span :P

Comment: I apologize for not telling you that but I didn't know display was part of the problem :(

Comment: This is frustrating... if I change display to none and then run it. It puts it right below the text box. Here is the div code <div id="status" style="display:none;background-image:url(menubar/ajax-loader.gif); width:16px; height:16px; background-repeat:no-repeat;padding-right:16px;"> and I toggle it with this code: $('#tblData').load('search_resident_criteria.asp?strval=' + SearchVar, function(){setTimeout(function(){$('#status').toggle();}, 2000);

Comment: That did it... so is Span different from div because it doesn't want to use the entire line like div does? Thanks again!!

Comment: yeah. spans don't want their own line, but divs do. That's the easiest way of thinking about it. read up on the "CSS display property" for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Just `float:right` the div and remove the 245px left margin so you aren't pushing the input too far away.